How to make label and label prefix italic in biblatex?
How can I make the label and label prefix (i.e. the "J1" here) both italic and not just the number?
I've tried \DeclareFieldFormat{label}{\mkbibemph{#1}} but it doesn't change anything (it makes both label prefix and label number upright) and doesn't give an error or a warning even.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nature, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{foo,
    author   = "X",
    title    = "Some Article",
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

% make whole label italic including prefix (doesn't work, only number is italic)
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Current Result:}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=J]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\subsection*{Desired Result:}
\emph{J1.} X. Some Article.

\end{document}



You kind of hinted at the answer yourself in a comment to your code:
% make whole label italic including prefix (doesn't work, only number is italic)
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

This is by design: the field labelnumber determines only the format of the number.
To change the appearance of the label prefix, you need to operate on the field labelprefix. See the biblatex documentation:

If the labelprefix option of \newrefcontext has been set in order to prefix all entries in a subbibliography with a fixed string, this string is available in the labelprefix field of all affected entries.

Just carry your previous approach over to the prefix and add the line
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelprefix}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

